# SharePoint 2010 Allow Code Blocks for a specific page

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, codeblocks

I am trying to use C# code in an aspx page within SharePoint 2010. I keep getting the "Code blocks are not allowed" error.

My aspx page located at (server)/SitePages/ajax.aspx: (edited in SharePoint Designer 2010 if it matters)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
    Response.Write("Hello world");
</script>
```

I added the following to web.config at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG

```
<PageParserPath VirtualPath="/SitePages/ajax.aspx" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" />
```

Here is the same line that I added to web.config, shown in context:

```
<SharePoint>
  <SafeMode 
        MaxControls = "200"  
        CallStack = "false"
        DirectFileDependencies ="10"
        TotalFileDependencies = "50"
        AllowPageLevelTrace = "false"
        >
        <PageParserPaths>
            <PageParserPath VirtualPath="/SitePages/ajax.aspx" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" />
        </PageParserPaths>
```

Why do I still get the "Code blocks" error? Is there another security switch somewhere?

(I know custom web parts are the preferred solution, but I don't think that will suffice here because the return value should be json - this is a page to hit via ajax to get data.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, you have to define PageParserPath element in an Web application web.config that is located C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories[application folder]\web.config.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload an aspx page to a document library (which is what you're doing when you use SharePoint Designer) that aspx page can't have inline code blocks and it can't have a code behind.  This is primarily a security mechanism.  It prevents any old user from uploading an aspx page with malicious content that will then be executed with full privileges on your server, and also serving content to (potentially) any user.

For an aspx page to execute code it needs to be compiled into a WSP and deployed to the GAC on the server.  When you do that you can either use inline code blocks or, better yet, have an aspx page with a code behind.  To publish that page to the site you would need to compile the project in visual studio into a WSP, deploy that to the server by logging into the machine with sufficient privileges, and then add and deploy the code.  This ensures that non-developers can't upload executable code to your site.

Finally, on a more unrelated note, since you don't actually want to display a page, but just JSON content, you probably shouldn't use an aspx page at all (although you *can*).  You should probably just create an HTTP handler or a web service that writes the appropriate content out.

Comment: This is certainly the best practice answer, but it is possible (see Dmitry's answer)